# Bloquear fechas input type date

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actualmente realizo un proyecto de una inmobiliaria, el cual tiene un módulo de citas.

*Problemática*
Se debe tener una restricción que la cita no se pueda programar de un día para otro sino que sean con tres días posteriores incluyendo la fecha actual, **es decir, si estamos a 26/01/2022, que el calendario muestre los días disponibles a partir del 29/01/2022.**

Logré bloquear las fechas posteriores a la actual: le coloco el **id=fechaReserva** que se encarga de ejecutar el **script** para bloquear los días posteriores a la fecha actual, pero no logro bloquear los tres días que se requieren.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Muestra el calendario en el modal**

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">FECHA<span class="required">*</span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-3">
      <input type="date" id="fechaReserva" onkeydown="return false" name="created_at"><br>
  </div>
```

**Script que bloquea los días anteriores a la fecha actual con variable *fechaReserva***

```
<script>
var fecha = new Date();
var anio = fecha.getFullYear();
var dia = fecha.getDate();
var _mes = fecha.getMonth(); //viene con valores de 0 al 11
_mes = _mes + 1; //ahora lo tienes de 1 al 12
if (_mes < 10) //ahora le agregas un 0 para el formato date
{
    var mes = "0" + _mes;
} else {
    var mes = _mes.toString;
}

var fecha_minimo = anio + '-' + mes + '-' + dia; // Nueva variable
document.getElementById("fechaReserva").setAttribute('min', fecha_minimo);  
fechaReserva.min = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];  </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No estabas tan mal encaminado con tu intento, excepto que no es necesario realizar cálculos con año, mes y día, basta con agregar días con `setDate()` como se sugiere en [este enlace](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/javascript/javascript-add-days-to-date/#a%C3%B1adiendo-d%C3%ADas-a-date-en-javascript).

```js
// Obtener fecha actual
let fecha = new Date();
// Agregar 3 días
fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 3);
// Obtener cadena en formato yyyy-mm-dd, eliminando zona y hora
let fechaMin = fecha.toISOString().split('T')[0];
// Asignar valor mínimo
document.querySelector('#fechaReserva').min = fechaMin;
```

```html
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">FECHA<span class="required">*</span>
      </label>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-3">
      <input type="date" id="fechaReserva" onkeydown="return false" name="created_at"><br>
  </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Triby es justo lo que necesitaba. Saludos